# R: readBin; how to set the file size correctly?

Tags: r

Is it possible to set the **n** parameter according to the actual file size?

Currently to read bin files I use the following code:

```
to.read = file(paste(cache_pfad,filename_save,sep = ""), "rb")
  data<-readBin(to.read, "raw",n = 90000000, endian = "little")
  close(to.read)`
```

where I set **n** to some big number.
Even the manual of **readBin** states:

> numeric. The (maximal) number of records to be read. You can use an over-estimate here, but not too large as storage is reserved for n items.

How could I set the size of n according to the file size?
Is there a better approach?

Comment: `file.info(filename)["size"]`? (I think you need to do this on the file *name*, not on `to.read` as above. This presumes you would pre-define `filename <- paste(cache_pfad, filename_save, sep = "")`, and then use `to.read <- file(filename)`, etc.)

Comment: perfect thank you! would you mind to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a file's size, use `file.info`:

```r
filename <- paste(cache_pfad,filename_save,sep = "")
filesize <- file.info(filename)["size"]
to.read <- file(filename, "rb")
data <- readBin(to.read, "raw", n = filesize, endian = "little")
close(to.read)
```